# multiple domains linking to same administration files

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

Forgive me if this is basic...I'm new to the configuration side of things.

I have built a web application that I want to reuse, but with smaller feature offering using a different domain name to make it easier for some of the basic users and I'm having difficulty figuring out the best way to do this.

I'm trying to avoid making a copy of the "administration" backend as it will be identical, just with a menu that does not display all the same features (i will handle the menu items displayed using PHP and based on the $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].  But I need the two different domain names to have separate web pages so I can showcase the two differing web applications.  I don't know how to configure this in apache, or even if this is a good way to do it.  I know how to create the two separate domains with their own folder structure, but I don't know how to make them use the same administrator backend.

Here's what I have.

/data/servers/www.website1.com/web
/data/servers/www.website2.com/web

I have a virtual host set up for each of these domains and the document root that points to the "web" folder for each of the different sites.

Under the "web" folder I have the following structure
./web/administrator

When the user goes to "www.website1.com" they need to be served up web pages specific to this site.  And when the user goes to "www.website2.com" they need to be served up web pages specific to the #2 site.  However, each site will have a "Sign In" link that points to a "Login.php" page that resides inside the "Adminstrator" folder.  And this is where I get confused how to make it work.  Upon log in I want the app to use the same web files found under "./www.website1.com/web/administrator", so I can manage the maintenance easier.  Inside the application I will display the menu options available to the user based on which site they came from.  My hope is that I can use the "Adminstration tools" I've already developed, without having to fork off the code and maintain 2 separate code bases and I'm hoping to leave the structure for website1.com in place, as it already has users and I am afraid of messing them up.

Is this possible?  Can someone help me figure out what I need to do to make this happen?

Here's how I currently have the virtual host set up for website1.com:

```
<VirtualHost 123.33.432.123:80>

#  General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "/data/servers/www.website1.com/web"
ServerName www.website1.com
ServerAlias *.website1.com
ServerAlias website1.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@website1.com
CustomLog "|/usr/local/sbin/cronolog /data/servers/www.website1.com/logs/access_log.%Y%m%d" "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\""

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.phtml index.htm index.php3 property-management-software.php

 <Directory "/data/servers/www.website1.com/web/">

    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm

    Options none
    AllowOverride All

    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
 </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I was thinking I'd add another virtual host for website2.com like this:

```
<VirtualHost 123.33.432.124:80>

#  General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "/data/servers/www.website2.com/web"
ServerName www.website2.net
ServerAlias *.website2.net
ServerAlias website2.net
ServerAdmin webmaster@website2.net
CustomLog "|/usr/local/sbin/cronolog /data/servers/www.website2.net/logs/access_log.%Y%m%d" "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\""

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.phtml index.htm index.php3 property-management-software.php

 <Directory "/data/servers/www.website2.net/web/">

    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm

    Options none
    AllowOverride All

    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [`Alias` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) to map a URL to a specific file/folder location:

```
Alias /administrator /data/servers/www.website1.com/web/administrator
```

So you would make your second vhost for your other domain then add this `Alias` so both `www.website1.com/administrator/` and `www.website2.net/administrator/` URL's will point to the same folder in your filesystem.

Edit: You may also need to include a `<Directory>` directive to give access to the aliased directory:

```
<Directory /data/servers/www.website1.com/web/administrator>
   AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm
   Options none
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: That sounds like it would work great!  I've updated the virtual host and put in the alias and put all the files in place.  When I click on the "sign in" link that goes to the /administrator/login.php page It gives me a "Forbidden" message saying i can't access the directory...do I need to change "website1.com" virtual directory to something else to allow this?  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Ronedog: See my edit re the `<Directory>` directive.

Comment: cOle2, that was it, that gave me permission to access it, thanks.  One other thing cropped up, now when I go to the login.php page, it is displayin all the .php code on the web page instead of displaying the HTML...any ideas?

Comment: @Ronedog: Add the same `AddType` code you have in your virtual host. I've updated the answer to include it.

Comment: cOle2, THANKS!!!  That did it...it's working perfectly...thanks for taking the time to help me out!